# Code is printing out \n with commas

Tags: python-3.x

I've began building a code which prints out the names of people along with their score achieved in their test in ascending order. It manages to print out the names with the score next to it but that's after it repeats several names unexpectedly.

```
info = open("resultsA.txt", "r")
    for line in info:
        x = line.split(",")
        names.append(x[0])
        scores = x[1] + x[2] + x[3]
        ascending = sorted(scores)
        names.append(ascending)
        print(*names, sep="\n")
```

[image: result]

Comment: `ascending` is a list. You probably want to use `names.extend(ascending)` (even though, as you can see, it contains some newlines and spaces that shouldn't be printed IMO)

Comment: And probably you also want `scores = x[1], x[2], x[3]`

Comment: Thank you very much. The issue with the commas and \n was sorted however I just do not understand why it is printing the same names and scores over again.

Comment: Please don't attach images of text to your question. If you have text output, include it *as text*. It makes it much easier for somebody else to copy and paste to add an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is doing two things. First, it appends a couple new values to the `names` list (another list of sorted scores, plus a single string). Then it prints the contents of the list, separated by newlines. That repeats several items in the list, as you can see in your output (abbreviated, since I can't be bothered typing in all the list contents):

```
 Korbin           # these first two lines are from the first iteration of the loop
 [ ... ]          #   1
 Korbin           # the next four are from the second iteration
 [ ... ]          #   2
 Bob              #   2
 [ ... ]          #   2
 Korbin           # The next six are from the third iteration
 [ ... ]          #   3
 Bob              #   3
 [ ... ]          #   3
 Dylan            #   3
 [ ... ]          #   3
 Korbin           # The next eight (which I'll not show all of) are from the fourth iteration
 [ ... ]          #   4
 # etc.
```

Your question suggests this is not what you wanted. I suspect you should either not bother with a list, and just `print` the name and list of other stats directly in the loop, or you should not print at all in the loop and just use a single `print` call at the end.

Here's an implementation that just does the printing directly in the loop, along with fixing the smaller issues with your line parsing:

```
info = open("resultsA.txt", "r")
    for line in info:
        x = line.strip().split(", ") # fix up the list contents
        print(x[0])
        scores = x[1:4]     # don't concatenate the strings, but slice the list
        ascending = sorted(scores)
        print(ascending)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has completely solved my issue. I was unaware that you were able to use x[1:4] which made this task much more easier for me. Thanks once again!